# Get Height and Width of squares in a square

Tags: calculus, geometry, rectangles

I have a square of fixed height and width for example 100x100.

Additionally I have the number of sub-squares which should fit into this square in this exapmle 20 sub-squares.

How can I calculate the height and the width of each sub-square?

Comment: what are we maximizing or minimizing for certainly we can fit a bunch of tiny squares into any box.

Comment: unless only the area of those sub-squares should be equal to the area of your big square you can just calculate $20\cdot x^2=100^2$. Otherwise this has no solution unless your number of sub-squares is a square number. (assuming you want to have maximal amount of subsquares in there)

Comment: are all the subsquares the same size?

Comment: @shaihorowitz no the super-square should be dynamic and the sub-squares should then change acordingly

Comment: @ctst so the super-square needs to be a perfect square to solve this?

Comment: @Snickbrack What do you mean with perfect or dynamic square? A square is a square is a rectangle with same lengths each side.

Comment: given the big square do you want all 20 sub squares to be the same size?

Comment: @ctst I meant a square... so it is not possible if the super-rectangle is not a square?

Comment: @shaihorowitz yes

Comment: Hint: width = height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ctst we have $20x^2 = 100^2$ then $x^2=100^2/20$ and $x=(100^2/20)^{.5}$ to get the width x of each square. $x = 10*5^{.5}$

For rectangles we have $20x*y=100^2$ then $x*y = (100^2/20)$ any point on this curve will be a solution.

Comment: this solution is not working for a non-square rectangle right?

Comment: yeah it assumed things are squares non squares are slightly more complicated.

Comment: But $10\sqrt{5} \simeq 22.4$ so you can actually fit only $4$ of those squares along one side of the $100$ square, therefore only $16$ of them *inside* the big square.